# Uniform distribution over $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: probability-theory, uniform-distribution

Suppose, on $\mathbb{R}^2$, that $X$ is a random variable which takes values uniformly at random over the $\textit{line segment}$ from $(0,0)$ to $(a,a)$, where $a > 0$ is a positive constant.

How can one find the distribution of $X$ over $\mathbb{R}^2$?

It seems that if we try to "project" $X$ to one-dimension, then we show get the uniform distribution over $\mathbb{R}$. But then, for example, we cannot conclude that
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}[X \in \text{line segment from $(0,0)$ to $(b,b)$}] = b/\sqrt{2}?
\end{equation}

Anyone gets an idea? Thanks very much.

Comment: The question is not "how" but "where". You can find the distribution in your first sentence.

Comment: What do you mean by "distrubution over $\mathbb R^2$"?  This distribution is not absolutely continuous, so there is no probability density function.

Comment: @GEdgar For example, I want to compute that probability $\mathbb{P}[X \in \text{line segment from $(0,0)$ to $(b,b)$}]$, for some $0 < b < 1$.

Comment: @GEdgar even it has no probability density, any random variable on $\mathbb R^n$ has a distribution...

Comment: What is the distribution of $X=U\cdot (a,a)$ where $U$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$?

Comment: The distribution of $X$ is the measure $\mu$ such that, for every Borel subset $B$ of $\mathbb R^2$, $$\mu(B)=\frac1a\int_0^a\mathbf 1_{x\in B}\,dx.$$ Thus $\mu$ has no density with respect to Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: @user251257 "...has a distribution".  Yes... and the first sentence of the question completely describes that distribution.  If Richie wants something else, he should tell us what he wants.

Comment: @user251257 That is what I do not understand. If you let $X = (aU, aU)$, where $U$ is uniform distributed on $[0,1]$, then it seems that $X$ takes values from $(0,0)$ to $(b,b)$ if and only if $U \in [0, b/a]$..

Comment: @Richie: yes. exactly.

Comment: @user251257 But then can we properly define what is the expectation of $X$, $\mathbb{E}[X]$? Is it just $\mathbb{E}[U]$?

Comment: What has the expectation of $X$ to do with it? Anyway $EX = EU \cdot(a,a) = (a/2, a/2)$.